# How to change the color of the PreferenceCategory divider in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-styles, divider, preferencefragment

I have an [android.support.v4.preference.PreferenceFragment](https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment) which uses the following PreferenceScreen:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Cat1"
    android:key="pref_cat1">
    <ListPreference
        android:key="pref_list1"
        android:title="@string/pref_list1"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_list1"
        android:entries="@array/pref_list1_entries"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_list1_entries"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_list1_default"/>
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_text2"
        android:title="@string/pref_text2"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Cat2"
    android:key="pref_cat2">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_text3"
        android:title="@string/pref_text3"
        />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

When displaying the PreferenceFragment, some dividers are shown between the preferences, but also under the name of each PreferenceCategory.
Though I can easily modify the color of the dividers between the preferences by accessing the PreferenceFragment's ListView, this has no effect on the PreferenceCategory dividers.

How to change also the color of such dividers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Define the `listSeparatorTextViewStyle` in your app's theme

Note that anything else which relies on this theme attribute will also change to use the style you define. If that's ok with you, it will look something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:...">
    ...
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/ListSeparatorText</item>
</style>

<style name="ListSeparatorText" parent="android:Widget.TextView"><!--parent is optional -->
    <item name="android:background">...</item>
    ...
</style>
```

2. Define a custom layout for your PreferenceCategories

The default layout for a `PreferenceCategory` is just a TextView. You can make your layout as simple or as complicated as you like, but somewhere should be a TextView with `android:id="@android:id/title"` so that the title is bound automatically.

Once you have a layout, use the `android:layout` attribute in your preference xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:title="Cat2"
    android:key="pref_cat2"
    android:layout="@layout/my_pref_category">
    ...
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Alternatively, you can define the `preferenceCategoryStyle` in your app's theme, in which case you don't need to use `android:layout` at all in your preference xml.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:...">
    ...
    <item name="android:preferenceCategoryStyle">@style/PreferenceCategoryStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PreferenceCategoryStyle" parent="android:Preference.Category">
    <item name="android:layout">@layout/my_pref_category</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks!
I had to provide a drawable for the white separator. I used an XML-defined drawable:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem in my `Prefernces` file. I solved it by the following steps:

**1:** Define file name `preferences_category.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+android:id/title"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <View style="@style/Divider" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**2:** Define `style` in the style xml file:

```
<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

**3:** add the `preferences_category.xml` file as `android:layout` attribute in the `preferences` xml file: :

```
 <PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="My title"
    android:layout="@layout/preferences_category">
```

Answer (score 2):

Now you can also set a custom drawable for your divider in code. I'm not sure about the older versions of support libraries, but at least now with AndroidX it works for me.

In your `PreferenceFragmentCompat` you can add:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_divider_drawable, requireActivity().getTheme()));
}
```

Also you can call `setDivider(null)` to remove the separator.